# Trig algebra problems, taking out a factor of tan

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

$$ \sin\theta-\cos\theta=0 $$
${\sin\theta\over\cos\theta}=\tan\theta $
$$ \cos\theta (\tan\theta-1)=0$$
$$\tan\theta=1$$  $$\cos\theta=0$$ 
$$\theta=45, 90$$ 
However the second solution is not true as $\sin90\neq\cos90$

Why does taking a factor of $\tan\theta $ out instead of just dividing through give incorrect solutions? Thanks, Jack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The factorization $$\sin \theta = \cos \theta \tan \theta$$ only holds where both sides are defined, namely on $$\Bbb R - \left\{\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi : n \in \Bbb Z \right\}.$$

In particular, $\tan \theta$ is not defined where $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ radians, that is, at $\theta = 90^{\circ}$. So, when one makes that factorization, one is necessarily discarding information about whether there is are solutions in the excluded set.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should not obtain the answer $\theta=90$.

The error occurs as you divide the whole equation by $\cos\theta$ and then multiply by  $\cos\theta$, without considering that dividing the equation by $\cos\theta=0$ can be an invalid move.

This kind of action can be only done when $\cos\theta\neq0$, that is, $\theta\neq90$.

So when you move from te first step to the second, you should first state that $\cos\theta\neq0$ to keep the following calculation make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of domain of validity of equations, and has nothing to see with trigonometry. Two equations can be logically equivalent only if they *formally* each one of them can de deduced from the other, **and** they have the same domain of validity.

With the same argument, you can say:$$A-B=0\iff B=0\enspace\text{or}\enspace \frac AB=1$$
However, supposing $A, B$ are defined for all $x$,the l.h.s. equation is always valid. While the r.h.s. is valid only for those $x$ such that $B\neq 0$.